# MCMC in R Modify Proposal

Tags: r, mcmc

I've been working with MCMC for population genetics and I have some doubts.
I'm not experienced in statistics and because of that I have difficulty.

I have code to run MCMC, 1000 iterations. I start by creating a matrix with 0's (50 columns = 50 individuals and 1000 lines for 1000 iterations).
Then I create a random vector to substitute the first line of the matrix. This vector has 1's and 2's, representing population 1 or population 2.
I also have genotype frequencies and the genotypes of the 50 individuals.
What I want is to, according to the genotype frequencies and genotypes, determine to what population an individual belongs.
Then, I'll keep changing the population assigned to a random individual and checking if the new value should be accepted.

```
niter <- 1000
z <- matrix(0,nrow=niter,ncol=ncol(targetinds))
z[1,] <- sample(1:2, size=ncol(z), replace=T)
lhood <- numeric(niter)
lhood[1] <- compute_lhood_K2(targetinds, z[1,], freqPops)
accepted <- 0
priorz <- c(1e-6, 0.999999)

for(i in 2:niter) {

    z[i,] <- z[i-1,]

    # propose new vector z, by selecting a random individual, proposing a new zi value
    selind <- sample(1:nind, size=1)
    # proposal probability of selecting individual at random
    proposal_ratio_ind <- log(1/nind)-log(1/nind)

    # propose a new index for the selected individual
    if(z[i,selind]==1) {
        z[i,selind] <- 2
    } else {
        z[i,selind] <- 1
    }

    # proposal probability of changing the index of individual is 1/2
    proposal_ratio_cluster <- log(1/2)-log(1/2)
    propratio <- proposal_ratio_ind+proposal_ratio_cluster

    # compute f(x_i|z_i*, p) 
    # the probability of the selected individual given the two clusters
    probindcluster <- compute_lhood_ind_K2(targetinds[,selind],freqPops)
    # likelihood ratio f(x_i|z_i*,p)/f(x_i|z_i, p)
    lhoodratio <- probindcluster[z[i,selind]]-probindcluster[z[i-1,selind]]  

    # prior ratio pi(z_i*)/pi(z_i)
    priorratio <- log(priorz[z[i,selind]])-log(priorz[z[i-1,selind]])

    # accept new value according to the MH ratio
    mh <- lhoodratio+propratio+priorratio
    # reject if the random value is larger than the MH ratio
    if(runif(1)>exp(mh)) {
        z[i,] <- z[i-1,] # keep the same z
        lhood[i] <- lhood[i-1] # keep the same likelihood
    } else { # if accepted
        lhood[i] <- lhood[i-1]+lhoodratio # update the likelihood
        accepted <- accepted+1 # increase the number of accepted
    }
}
```

It is asked that I have to change the proposal probability so that the new proposed values are proportional to the likelihood. This leads to a Gibbs sampling MCMC algorithm, supposedly.

I don't know what to change in the code to do this. I also don't understand very well the concept of proposal probability and how to chose the prior.

Grateful if someone knows how to clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current proposal is done here:

```
# propose a new index for the selected individual
    if(z[i,selind]==1) {
        z[i,selind] <- 2
    } else {
        z[i,selind] <- 1
    }
```

if the individual is assigned to cluster 1, then you propose to switch assignment deterministically by assigning them to cluster 2 (and vice versa).

You didn't show us what freqPops is, but if you want to propose according to freqPops then I believe the above code has to be replaced by

```
z[i,selind] <- sample(c(1,2),size=1,prob=freqPops)
```

(at least that is what I understand when you say you want to propose based on the likelihood - however, that statement of yours is unclear).

For this now to be a valid mcmc gibbs sampling algorithm you also need to change the next line of code:

```
proposal_ratio_cluster <- log(freqPops[z[i-1,selind]])-log(fregPops[z[i,selind]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, @papgeo! What I really want to do is to propose according to likelihood values calculated for an individual. 2 likelihood values for that individual, one for each population. With your answer I think I could do that part, I just used the likelihood values in prob so that the most likely will be chosen more times.

Comment: about the second part, shouldn't  fregPops[z[i,selind]] be first and freqPops[z[i-1,selind]] second? So that it is: log(freqPops[z[i,selind]])-log(fregPops[z[i-1,selind]]) ? Also, can you please explain me or give a source to Gibbs explanation in a similar case? Sorry for asking so much!

Comment: The order I suggested I believe is the correct one. It comes to correct possible imbalance in the proposal. So changing the proposal, shouldn't have much of an effect on the output. But changing the prior can have an effect. Currently the prior says that the first group is very unlikely. 1e-6.